# declaring 2 controllers for use in a single page

Tags: angularjs, node.js, loopback

I  have 2 controllers that i want to use. One of them is ModalDemoCtrl amd the other is ReportController. How do i declare both controllers that shares the same state, url and templateUrl?

## app.js

```
angular
    .module('app', [
        'ui.router',
        'lbServices',
        'ngAnimate', 
        'ui.bootstrap'
    ])
    .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('report', {
        url: '/report',
        templateUrl: 'views/report.html',
        controller: 'ModalDemoCtrl',
        authenticate: true
        })
        .state('report', {
        url: '/report',
        templateUrl: 'views/report.html',
        controller: 'ReportController',
        authenticate: true
        });
```

Comment: What are you using the controllers for? Because depending on what you're doing, instead of assigning two controllers into a single state, I'd either factor it out into a directive, put the logic into a server, or abstract out a parent state controller that handles the logic in the child states. It really depends on what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try something like this

```
<div ng-controller="FirstController">
    <p>Stuff ..</p>
</div>

<div class="menu" ng-controller="SecondController">
    <p>Other stuff ...</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have more than one controllers in single page, but you cannot have multiple ng-app.
You then define this module and define all your controllers in this module:

```
//app.js

var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router']);

     app.config(['$stateProvider','$urlRouterProvider',
      function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
        $stateProvider.
          state('report', {
            url:'/report',
            templateUrl: 'views/report.html'
        })
    }]);

    app.controller('ModalDemoCtrl', function($scope) {

        $scope.message = 'This is ModalDemoCtrl';

    });
    app.controller('ReportController', function($scope) {

        $scope.message = 'This is  ReportController';

    });



 //report.html

   <div class="container">
        //ModalDemoCtrl
        <div ng-controller = 'ModalDemoCtrl'>
         {{ message }}
        </div>
        //ReportController
        <div ng-controller = 'ReportController'>
        {{ message }}
        </div>

    </div>
```